# How to get the overall count in a multiple selection system with ranking

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a web project in which I am trying to collect users' emotional feelings toward art collections. A hybrid dual list on the website allows users to select three options from 12 options and then rank the selected three as 1st, 2nd, and 3rd. There are 1000 data points in this project, which means there are 1000 distinct art collections for the users to vote on, each of the art collections has the same 12 options.

collection_poll

```
+-------+--------------------+  
|   id  |   collection_name  |   
+-------+--------------------+
|   1   |    collection 1    | 
|   2   |    collection 2    | 
|   3   |    collection 3    |  
|   4   |    collection 4    |
|   5   |    collection 5    |
|  ...  |        ...         |
+-------+--------------------+
```

option

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|   collection_id    |      option id     |      Text      |
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|         1          |          1         |    Emotion 1   |
|         1          |          2         |    Emotion 2   |
|         1          |          3         |    Emotion 3   |
|         1          |          4         |    Emotion 4   |
|         1          |          5         |    Emotion 5   |
|         1          |          6         |    Emotion 6   |
|         1          |          7         |    Emotion 7   |
|         1          |          8         |    Emotion 8   |
|         1          |          9         |    Emotion 9   |
|         1          |          10        |    Emotion 10  |
|         1          |          11        |    Emotion 11  |
|         1          |          12        |    Emotion 12  |
|         2          |          1         |    Emotion 1   |
|         2          |          2         |    Emotion 2   |
|         2          |          3         |    Emotion 3   |
|         2          |          4         |    Emotion 4   |
|         2          |          5         |    Emotion 5   |
|        ...         |         ...        |       ...      |
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------|
```

vote

```
+--+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id|user_id|collection_id|1st_option_id|2nd_option_id|3rd_option_id|
+--+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1 |   1   |      1      |      1      |      8      |      12     |
|2 |   2   |      1      |      3      |      1      |      8      |
|3 |   3   |      1      |      1      |      8      |      3      |
|4 |   1   |      2      |      1      |      8      |      12     |
|5 |   2   |      2      |      3      |      12     |      8      |
|6 |   3   |      2      |      1      |      3      |      12     |
+--+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

This table records each vote and specifies which collection the user votes and the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd options the user ranks.

How do I use MySQL to get this table?

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+  
| collection_id | option_id | 1st_count | 2nd_count | 3rd_count |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1       |     1     |     2     |     1     |     0     |
|       1       |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |
|       1       |     3     |     1     |     0     |     1     |
|       1       |     4     |     0     |     0     |     0     |
|      ...           ...         ...         ...         ...    |
|       1       |     8     |     0     |     2     |     1     |
|      ...           ...         ...         ...         ...    |
|       1       |     12    |     0     |     0     |     1     |
|       2       |     1     |     2     |     0     |     0     |
|       2       |     2     |     0     |     0     |     0     |
|       2       |     3     |     1     |     1     |     0     |
|      ...           ...         ...         ...         ...    |
|       2       |     8     |     0     |     1     |     1     |
|      ...           ...         ...         ...         ...    |
|       2       |     12    |     0     |     1     |     2     |
|      ...           ...         ...         ...         ...    |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

which uses collection_poll.id and option.id to get the result from table_vote.

I have

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW "public"."poll_results_first_option_count" AS
SELECT
  vote.collection_id,
  vote.first_option_id,
  count(*) AS first_count
FROM
  vote
GROUP BY
  vote.collection_id,
  vote.first_option_id
ORDER BY
  vote.collection_id,
  vote.first_option_id;
```

to get the count of each rank but cannot put them together.

Comment: This is pivot. It is not implemented in MySQL. You may use stored procedure which pivots your data or use some another method (for example, conditional aggregation). See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot -you'd find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer does not provide the correct results. You need to be `LEFT JOIN`ing, starting from your `option` table and including `option_id` in the JOIN criteria:

```
SELECT  `o`.`collection_id`, `o`.`option_id`,
        `1st_count`,
        `2nd_count`,
        `3rd_count`
    FROM `option` `o`
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `1st_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `1st_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t1` USING (`collection_id`, `option_id`)
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `2nd_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `2nd_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t2` USING (`collection_id`, `option_id`)
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `3rd_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `3rd_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t3` USING (`collection_id`, `option_id`)
    ORDER BY `o`.`collection_id`, `o`.`option_id`;
```

In your question you state:

> each of the art collections has the same 12 options

If this is the case, then there is no need to link them in your `option` table. Instead you can just have the twelve options (and drop `collection_id` column) and CROSS JOIN to `collection_poll` to build the full list:

```
SELECT  `cp`.`id`, `o`.`option_id`,
        `1st_count`,
        `2nd_count`,
        `3rd_count`
    FROM `collection_poll` `cp`
    CROSS JOIN `option` `o`
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `1st_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `1st_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t1` ON `cp`.`id` = `t1`.`collection_id` AND `o`.`option_id` = `t1`.`option_id`
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `2nd_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `2nd_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t2` ON `cp`.`id` = `t2`.`collection_id` AND `o`.`option_id` = `t2`.`option_id`
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT `collection_id`, `3rd_option_id` AS `option_id`, COUNT(*) AS `3rd_count` FROM `vote` GROUP BY 1, 2 ) AS `t3` ON `cp`.`id` = `t3`.`collection_id` AND `o`.`option_id` = `t3`.`option_id`
    ORDER BY cp.id, o.option_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the better answer! Actually, I did use left join based on the previous answer and get the correct result I want. But you provided the CROSS JOIN method that I think would be the best solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Do the sums

```
SELECT  collection_id,
        1st_option_id,
        COUNT(*) AS 1st_count
    FROM votes
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

and do similarly for the others

Step 2:  Put them together (somewhat like "pivot"):

```
SELECT  collection_id, 
        1st_count,
        2nd_count,
        3rd_count
    FROM ( ... ) AS t1
    JOIN ( ... ) AS t2  USING(collection_id)
    JOIN ( ... ) AS t3  USING(collection_id)
    ORDER BY collection_id;
```

where the "..." comes from step 1